# set order of ant target when using target overriding

Tags: java, ant

I'm overriding a call to compile from a shared build.xml to call compile-generated first in my custom build.

I add my overriden compile target with depends="compile-generated, shared.compile" as shown and explained in the documentation. However, my compile-generated target is now called as the *first* dependency for the overriden target rather than (as I need it to be) the last dependency.

Does anyone know how to fix it so the original dependencies on the "shared.compile" are called first and my overriden dependency is called last when the compile target is called?

my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="ExternalTools" basedir="." default="jar">

 <import file="../../../shared-build.xml" />

<target name="compile" depends="compile-generated, Shared.compile"/>
<target name="compile-generated">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.gen.dir}"
         destdir="${classes.dir}"
         classpathref="build.classpath"
         debug="on"/>
</target>


</project>
```

Shared "build.xml" compile target:

```
<target name="compile" depends="prepare-staging-dirs,copy-dependlib-jars" description="Compile into stage directory">
                <javac srcdir="${src.dir}"
                       destdir="${classes.dir}"
                       classpathref="build.classpath"
                           includeantruntime="false"
                       debug="on"/>

                <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
                  <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.properties,**/*.xml,**/*.xsd,**/*.html" />
                </copy>
        </target>
```

Comment: You should never use the `depends` attribute to dictate the order of dependencies, as the order they're written in is only incidental and not enforced. If dependencies need to run in a particular order, make one depend on the other.

Comment: well fair point but I am trying to avoid changing the shared build.xml file which is sort of the whole point. so I guess you're saying in other words that what I'm asking is not possible without changing the shared file?

Comment: No, just make your custom dependency depend on the shared dependencies as well. I'll add an answer that illustrates this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies aren't ordered, they're hierarchical. If two dependencies in the same hierarchy are running in an undesired order, simply have one depend on the other.

In your case, you can tell `compile-generated` to depend on your shared `compile`'s dependencies.

In the shared build.xml:

```
<target name="compile" depends="copy-dependlib-jars,prepare-staging-dirs">
    <echo message="Running root.compile" />
</target>

<target name="copy-dependlib-jars">
    <echo message="Running copy-dependlib-jars" />
</target>

<target name="prepare-staging-dirs">
    <echo message="Running prepare-staging-dirs" />
</target>
```

Custom build.xml:

```
<import file="build.xml" />

<target name="compile" depends="compile-generated,root.compile">
    <echo message="Running custom compile" />
</target>

<target name="compile-generated" depends="copy-dependlib-jars,prepare-staging-dirs">
    <echo message="Running compile-generated" />
</target>
```

> ant compile

```
 copy-dependlib-jars:
      [echo] Running copy-dependlib-jars

 prepare-staging-dirs:
      [echo] Running prepare-staging-dirs

 compile-generated:
      [echo] Running compile-generated

 root.compile:
      [echo] Running root.compile

 compile:
      [echo] Running custom compile
```